# Powershell if then

Tags: sql, powershell, if-statement

I'm having an issue with the if then.

```
    $result = getMachineInfo $rlprddeploy $mdt
"-MachineID-    -LastContactAt-          -LastIP-   -Deployment Receiver Version-"
$machine = $result.MachineID
$result | % { '{0,-10} {1,23} {2,16} {3,20}' -f $_.MachineID, $_.LastContactAt, $_.LastIP, $_.DeploymentReceiverVersion }
#$result | ft -auto
```

if $_.DeploymentReceiverVersion is less than 5.46.54 then I'm going to send a file to do an update. If the version is 5.55 then nothing needs to be done.

I've been banging my head against this for a week now and I can't figure it out. Every $_.blahblah is information pulled from an SQL table on a server.

We've been sending out updates manually and I'd like to stop that.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell's If statement can be written just like any C like language:

```
if ($true) {Write-Host "True Yo" }
```

That said, you haven't posted exactly what your issues is, so this somewhat generic:

Creating a custom object:

```
$dep = New-Object psobject -Property @{DeploymentReceiverVersion = "5.000.11"; AppName = "OxenTails" }
```

Comparing this is going to pose a potential problem:

```
$dep.DeploymentReceiverVersion.GetType()
```

The version is a string, so the comparison is comparing strings:

```
$dep.DeploymentReceiverVersion -lt "5.000.12"
```

gives an expected result, but

```
$dep.DeploymentReceiverVersion -lt "5.000.101"
```

does not.

This however could work to compare each set of numbers:

```
$parts = $dep.DeploymentReceiverVersion.Split('.')
if ([int]$parts[0] -lt 6 -and [int]$parts[1] -lt 001 -and [int]$parts[2] -lt 101) {
#Do Stuff!
}
```

Additionally, as pointed out by @TheMadTechnician there is the System.Version type `[Version]`

It can be used with one of the overload methods:

```
[Version]::new(parts[0],parts[1], parts[2]) -lt [Version]::new(5,46,54)
```

Which is marginally more readable.

Comment: There's a `[version]` type, so you can cast the version number as a `[version]` for comparisons! `[version]$dep.DeploymentReceiverVersion -lt "5.000.101"` evaluates correctly. Keep in mind PowerShell uses the left hand object for type reference when performing comparisons, so if you type case the left item PowerShell automagically tries to convert the right side item to the same type.

Comment: To add to @TheMadTechnician's helpful comment: please don't use `Write-Host` in your code, so as to avoid confusion. The misconception that `Write-Host` is for writing _output_ is far too common.

Comment: @mkelement0 yes, obviously not code meant for anything besides illustrating a concept. And the [version] type is new, but potentially super useful